# What effect does airfoil sweep have on lift production?

Tags: aircraft-design

In discussion of incorporating sweep into vertical stabilizer designs, it is often said that sweep can create more torque moment around the CG because it moves the center of (stabilizer) pressure further back.

Yet, sweep also introduces a different airflow pattern than a straight wing, resulting in air being "plowed" outwards "underneath" as AoA increases, and air being pulled inwards (toward the root) on the low pressure side.

Interestingly, this actually manifests into a useful lifting vortex as sweep increases more, but the Coefficient of lift on the straight airfoil is greater.  The straight airfoil (without high lift devices) will stall at a lower angle of attack.

All well and good, but does anyone have some hard numbers on lifting and stalling properties as sweep progresses from 10-20-30-45-60 degrees?

Would sweeping a stabilizer back 30 degrees actually result in more longitudinal stability, or would it just have more resistance to abruptly stalling at a higher AoA?

Comment: [This](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/20050019390) might be helpful

Comment: @sophit see page 6.  We're certainly on the right track.

Comment: And [more](https://aerodyn.org/sweepback/) here!

Comment: There is some content in "Aerodynamics for Naval Aviators" that might help -- https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/media/00-80t-80.pdf -- see pp 74-77-- also 228-232 and *especially the uppermost graph on page 228*.  I'm not planning to answer at present; feel free to use this in any answer.

Comment: @quietflyer excellent content.  So we wonder what a 120 knot Cessna is doing with a swept fin anyways.  Probably more to smooth crosswind effects, and it does look good.

Comment: side observation vertical stabilizer are variable swept wings about airplane's pitch axis. Mooney swept forward vertical stabilizer gets closer to being straight at low speed high AoA. reverse is valid for Cessna becoming even more swept back at low speed high AoA

Comment: if a greater mass of air is plown outwards than pulled inwards, then swept back vertical stabilizers during lateral gust should induce a nose up moment, where unswept ones should produce no moment about pitch axis. Yet I'm not sure if more air is plown out than pulled in. I may ask how much lateral lift is created by half a swept wing.